# mongoose equivalences for updateOne and replaceOne (mongo native drivers) restful patch put

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

mongodriver has method to update accord to http methods restful.
What is the equivalences in Moongose ?

```
METHOD      MongoDriver  Detail                  Mongoose?

PATCH       updateOne    Partial Update          findOneAndUpdate?
PUT         replaceOne   Whole replacement doc   ...
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The Mongoose equivalent to `updateOne` is [`update`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.update) with the `multi: false` option (the default).

The Mongoose equivalent to `replaceOne` is also `update`, but with the `overwrite: true` option.

**Mongoose 4.x Update**

Mongoose models now directly support [`updateOne`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.updateOne) and [`replaceOne`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.replaceOne) methods.